# Notation regarding polynomial ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Suppose $F[x]$ is a field, and $p(x) \in F[x]$ be a polynomial. We want to quotient $F[x]$ with the ideal generated by $p(x)$.

While the commonly used notation to denote that $F[x]/p(x)$, isn't the notation kinda misleading because $p(x)$ is not an ideal ?

I think $F[x]/p(x)F[x]$ should be the correct notation since $p(x)F[x]$ is an ideal.

Comment: You also can use $F[x]/\bigl(p(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: The same problem ("kinda misleading"?) is with $\Bbb{Z}/n$ or $\Bbb{Z}/(n)$ or $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. Even worse, $\Bbb{Z}_p$, which are also $p$-adic integers.